# XPath Expression Problem

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML snippet, http://paste.enzotools.org/show/1209/ , and I want to extract the  tag that has a text() descendant with the value of "172.80" (it's the fourth  node from that snippet). My attempts so far have been:

```
'descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure" and contains(descendant::text(), "172.80")]'
'descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure" and contains(div/text(), "172.80")]'
'descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure" and div[contains(text(), "172.80")]]'
```

but neither of them selects anything. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Tha HTML snippet is not valid XML/HTML - there is `title` attribute that starts with `<img`. The `<` should be escaped to `&lt;`.

Comment: Please fix you code. I'm getting error:  "Error: Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'"

Comment: What are you using to apply these XPath queries? jQuery? Selenium? It matters.

Comment: I'm scraping with Scrapy and using Scrapy's selectors for HTML parsing. The selectors are based on libxml2. Here is the URL of the page in question, so you can try your XPath expressions directly http://www.booking.com/hotel/tr/swissotelistanbul.html?checkin=2010-11-15;checkout=2010-11-16 . And yes, I've also noticed that the HTML is not valid, although it appears valid in the console.

Comment: re: validity, what @Oded means is that it's not well-formed XML. ("Valid" refers to conforming to a schema, which is not relevant here.) However tools that apply XPath to HTML, like Scrapy and Selenium, use the DOM tree representation of the HTML so they don't care that much whether it's well-formed XML or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing node set to function calls, do note that if the function signature doesn't declare a node set argument then it will cast the the first node from that node set.

So, I think you need this XPath expression:

```
descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure"][div[text()[contains(.,'172.80')]]]
```

*Test for a text node child of `div`*

or

```
descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure"]
              [div[descendant::text()[contains(.,'172.80')]]]
```

*Test for a text node descendant of `div`*

or

```
descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure"]
              [descendant::text()[contains(.,'172.80')]]
```

*Test for a text node descendat of `td`*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//td[contains(string(.), '172.80')]">
```

The string() function will give you all the text in the current and descendant nodes wherease text() just gives you the text in the current (context) node.

Of course, you extend the xpath selector to filter on the class names too...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//td[contains(string(.), '172.80')][@class='roomPrice figure']">
```

And as stated in the comments above, you're posted xml/html is invalid as it stands.

Comment: That's one way to do it. Note that the explicit `string(.)` is redundant, as the first argument will get converted to a string implicitly. The only drawback is that every td could be converted to a string this way, which would involve a lot of unnecessary string concatenation to build strings that will be thrown away. But that may not be a problem for small web pages.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to select the `td` element in specified class, that has a descendant text node containing the value "172.80".

I'm assuming the context node is the `<tr>` (or some ancestor of it).

The attempts you listed all suffer from the problem that `contains()` converts its first argument to a single string, using only the first node of the nodeset. So if the `td` or `div` has a descendant or child text node before the one that contains "172.80", the one containing "172.80" will not be noticed.

Try this:

```
'descendant::td[@class="roomPrice figure" and
                descendant::text()[contains(., "172.80")]]'
```

Comment: @LucianU: you're welcome. You should probably upvote the answers that you think are helpful, and accept one of them.

Comment: LarsH, I tried upvoting, but I don't have enough reputation for that. Btw, thank you also for explaining the problem clearly. I understand now what was wrong and hopefully won't repeat the mistake.

Comment: @LucianU: ok, no problem. It's tricky, understanding which parts of XPath support "general (nodeset) comparisons" and which parts don't.